# index de dataframe no me permite usarlo para visualizacion de datos con matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Requiero de usar el index de un dataframe como datos para un grafico hecho en matplotlib, pero cuando intento establecer este index como variable para el eje x, me devuelve el error `KeyError: 'date'`. Ya se el origen del error, pero no se como hacer para poder usar el index como datos (no puedo cambiar el index, debe ser ese). Probe asignando `x = df['date'].values()` para poder obtener unicamente los valores de esta columna, pero no me lo permite y devuelve el error anterior. Este es mi codigo actual:

```
df = pd.read_csv('fcc-forum-pageviews.csv')
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)


# Clean data
df = df[(df["value"] >= df["value"].quantile(0.025)) & 
        (df["value"] <= df["value"].quantile(0.975))] # possible mistake here, df too 
short
print(df)


def draw_line_plot():
    # Draw line plot
    x = df['date']
    y = df['values']
    fig = plt.plot(x, y, title='Daily freeCodeCamp Forum Page Views 5/2016-12/2019', 
data=df)    

# Save image and return fig (don't change this part)
fig.figure.savefig('line_plot.png')
return fig
```

Por si lo desean, este es el ejercicio que debo realizar:

- Use Pandas to import the data from "fcc-forum-pageviews.csv". Set the index to the "date" column.
- Clean the data by filtering out days when the page views were in the top 2.5% of the dataset or bottom 2.5% of the dataset.
- Create a draw_line_plot function that uses Matplotlib to draw a line chart similar to "examples/Figure_1.png". The title should be "Daily freeCodeCamp Forum Page Views 5/2016-12/2019". The label on the x axis should be "Date" and the label on the y axis should be "Page Views".

Y la URL para descargar el .cvs es [esta](https://replit.com/github/freeCodeCamp/boilerplate-page-view-time-series-visualizer). El nombre del archivo es 'fcc-forum-pageviews.csv'.

Cualquier tipo de ayuda es agradecida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deberias usar df.index.values, te recomiendo la sigiente modificacion.

```
df = pd.read_csv('fcc-forum-pageviews.csv')
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)


# Clean data
df = df[(df["value"] >= df["value"].quantile(0.025)) & 
        (df["value"] <= df["value"].quantile(0.975))] # possible mistake here, df too 
print(df)


def draw_line_plot():
    # Draw line plot
    x = df.index.values
    y = df['value']
    plt.title='Daily freeCodeCamp Forum Page Views 5/2016-12/2019'
    fig = plt.plot(x, y)

# Save image and return fig (don't change this part)
fig.figure.savefig('line_plot.png')
return fig
```